# Build deb package version with command line option

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, deb

Newbie to build deb package. I've a build script to generate packages for Ubuntu. Version number is there in `changelog`. I'd like to automate the process of building deb packages without touching `changelog` using a `version` file and the file consists of only version number something like `1.0.0`.

How can I pass the version number to debuild command?

```
   debuild --no-lintian --preserve-envvar=PATH --check-dirname-level 0 --no-tgz-check -uc -us
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is, that a new version of a debian package is determined by a changelog entry. Adding the entry can be automated using the [dch](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/dch.1.en.html) helper script.

Comment: I've ended up doing this using -  `sudo dch -v "${version}" -D "trusty" "all latest updates"`

Comment: Why are you using sudo? For updating the changelog you should not need it and the usual way to build a package is ``dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot``. I would try to avoid sudo, first for security reasons and second just in case that the package would accidentally install something in the system instead of in the package directory. The ``fakeroot`` program fakes the user id during the installation.

Comment: makes sense. I'll remove `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but I can think of 2 ways to accomplish this.

The first would be to read all options from a file and execute debuild on it including the version number as such (assuming you make 'debuild' a global alias or function):

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/user/build_options.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    debuild $line
done <"$file"
```

Where your build_options.txt file looks something like:

```
--version 1.0.0 --no-lintian --preserve-envvar=PATH --check-dirname-level 0 --no-tgz-check -uc -us
--version 1.0.1 --no-lintian --preserve-envvar=PATH --check-dirname-level 0 --no-tgz-check -uc -us
...
```

The second method depends on the language you are writing your "debuild" script in.  I assume you're creating a wrapper around `dpkg-deb`?  Essentially, you write a function for the `--version` option which expects a path to a file to open and read in the version numbers line by line, comma separated, etc.  In Python, this can be accomplished with the `argparse` module (see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).  Another great working example can be seen in this TensorFlow script: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py.

The general idea for the 2nd method is writing a function that reads the version file using the `--version` flag, but this solution will be specific to your language of choice.  Possibly related: https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/wiki/Automatic-RPM-DEB-Packages-module-building.

Comment: Thanks @shellcat_zero for your effort. I've ended up doing this automate updating changelog using `dch`